# How to create a AutoHotkey like hotstring using C++?

Tags: c++, autohotkey

I have figured out an effective way to create a hotkey using C++.

AutoHotkey example Alt+A to run a file.

```
Alt & a::
Run, C:\blah\blah\blah\abc.png
Return
```

C++ example Alt+A to run a file.

```
while(true) {
if( GetKeyState(VK_MENU) & 0x8000 ) {
if( GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000 ) {
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\blah\\blah\\blah\\abc.png", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}}}
```

I now want to understand how to create a hotstring using C++. For example how can I convert following AutoHotkey code into C++?

```
::abc::
Run, C:\blah\blah\blah\abc.png
Return
```

Comment: What have you tried doing to achieve it?

Comment: @UnholySheep Well first of all I googled obviously. No luck. I searched stackoverflow, superuser and autohotkey forum. No luck. I searched "C++ hotstring" in google. No luck. After that I didn't really know what to do. You see, hotstring is like a feature especially invented by AutoHotkey so no one seems to want to do it in another language like C++. Since the source code of autohotkey is C++ I know it can be done but how?

Comment: I meant what kind of code have you tried writing. The obvious solution would be to take a `string` and loop through the characters and check them with `GetKeyState`

Comment: @UnholySheep I haven't tried any code. Whatever logic I could think of had missing pieces. for example for ::abc:: you have to press spacebar for the text to disappear and code code to execute right. I thought that the spacebar could be a hotkey. It will detect the last word typed before space bar was pressed. convert the word to string, press backspace thrice using keyboard event and do rest of stuff. But how to detect the typed word?

Comment: the string could be use in an if statement. I forgot to mention that

Comment: The simplest method would probably be to use a state machine to keep track of the characters seen so far.

Comment: @AndrewSun if you have used AutoHotkey and you know what a hotstring is than please guide me further because I don't know how to use a state machine

Comment: @happy Basically, loop until you see 'a', then loop until you see 'b', etc, until you see a space - then run the command. If any any point you pressed something that wasn't what you were expecting (e.g. waiting for 'b' and you pressed 'c'), then you reset and wait for 'a' again.

Comment: @AndrewSun please check back in about five minutes. I hope that is ok I think I understand what u mean so I am going to post an example sort of.

Comment: @AndrewSun I edited the question. Is this what you meant.

Comment: @AndrewSun Actually, there is a small flaw in it. If the hotstring is `aaaaab` and the user pressed `aaaaaab`, there is a match but the algorithm won't detect it.

Comment: @AndrewSun how will i ever achieve this if i can't figure out the pseudo code? do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @FeiXiang can you help fix this algorithm

Comment: I'm not an expert here with what I assume is the Windows API and what you're trying to do. But perhaps take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Comment: @FeiXiang that stuff is way to complicated

Comment: I know, I don't even fully understand those yet. Sorry, but I can't help more.

Comment: The naive algorithm will probably work for you though. Try keeping a history of what the user has pressed.